# Django AllAuth does not extend 'base.html', despite base.html existing in templates

Tags: python, css, django, django-allauth

base.html works for all other url links, but as soon as I load localhost:8000/accounts/ (e.g. logout or login), the css template does not work at all. The functionality still works, it's just the css that isn't working.

This is as per the tutorial (From 8:22 to 10:44): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bopkZBbIa7c. I have followed the tutorial step by step, yet it gives a different result than the tutorial. (Just want to reiterate the functionality is fine, just plain django css)

My current settings.py is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
    'posts',

    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('blog/', blog, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<id>', post, name = 'post_detail'),
    path('search/', search, name = 'search'),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('accounts/profile/', blog, name='post_list')
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Django version 3.1.4
Python 3

Comment: Can you verify that your site is actually loading the css and not getting a 404 error or similar, using the network tab ?

Comment: Here is the loaded web file. https://pasteboard.co/JEY90qw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. The cause**: `allauth`'s login.html is using its own `base.html`.

Django will look for allauth's `login.html` in `allauth` package. You can inspect that under

```
myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/account/login.html
```

The template under this folder will use `base.html` of `allauth`'s located at:

```
myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/
```

not the one you created under `/templates`.

**2. How to force `allauth`'s login.html to use your own `base.html`?**

I assume that

- a. you have already made a project-wise `templates` folder.
- b. under settings.py, you have this under `TEMPLATES=[`

```
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

Then, you will generate a folder called `account` and put `login.html` in it.

```
templates/account/login.html
```

Now, when django looks for template `login.html`, it will first look into `templates/account/login.html` rather than allauth package's template. In this case, the template will use `your own base.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble finding
```...site-packages/allauth``` 
in my directory as per the image below
https://pasteboard.co/JEXRLBk.png
Any help would be appreciated

Furthermore, I checked pip3 freeze, and codun't find allauth either. Not too sure if it's relevant.

Comment: I could not find it either the picture you showed. could you search ```allauth``` or ```account``` or ```socialaccount```?

Comment: its odd that here yo do not have "tinymce" either.

Comment: Hi ha-neul, the image is in the pasteboard link in the comment. Regarding the folders allauth or account or social account, it doesn't seem to exist in my project directory (searched with ctrl + p). Wierd, but the project displays full functionality of the imported libraries.

Comment: My apologies, it seems that in pip3 freeze, allauth and tinymce are are in there under django-allauth and django-tinymce.